How to write the Profile distribution (Profile Likelihood) in Mathematica?
Im new to Mathematica. I want to use the resuls that I got from the MCMC chains and use this method 2203.16285 to get the Profile Distribution. I found even the steps from a presentation the author gave. Thse are the steps:

Build a grid for the parameter of interest.
At each knot, search for the maximum value of the posterior and save it (no need of removing the points of the burn-in phase).

(Here is the formula)

Plot the result and compute confidence intervals.

Still, Im confused about how can I write it.
I tried to write it but I couldnt. My data are simple .dat file.

Try this
I used the trivial example from the paper you included, thank you for that.
I do not know whether you are looking for the values for α and β which maximize your function or whether you are looking for a symbolic solution in terms of α where β maximizes that. I have shown a method for each of those. I am not happy with the second method. I'll think a little more about that and see if I can come up with a method that I am happier with.
p[α_,β_]:=5/(21 Pi)(E^(-1/4(α^2+β^2))+E^(-1/4(α-3.5)^2-100β^2))
Plot3D[p[α,β],{α,-3,6},{β,-3,3}]
Chop[Maximize[p[α,β],{α,β}]]

which returns
{0.080024,{α->0.228106,β->0}}

and
p[α,β]/.ToRules[Reduce[D[p[α,β],β]==0,β,Reals]//Simplify]

which returns
(5*(E^(-1/4*(-3.5 + α)^2) + E^(-1/4*α^2)))/(21*Pi)

See if you can adapt this to your actual problem and please report back what you did.
And, please test this brutally to try to make certain that I've made no mistakes. Thank you

Thank you so much for your reply. I want to find the maximum value of the posterior. I tried to use what you suggested, but I still have some problems. I will post here when I finish it.
